# When to use $(this) and isn't that slower?

Tags: jquery, comparison, selector, this

In jQuery we can do like...

```
$('.button').click( function() {

    $(this).hide();

} );
```

But we can do like this too, of course:

```
$('.button').click( function() {

    $('.button').hide();

} );
```

What're advantages of using *this*? Isn't that slower?

I think the answer for this question will be something like...

> There are situations when only way is to use *this*.

Show me example of that situation then! :)

Which should I use primary (if both would work)?

Comment: Why would `$(this)` be slower than scanning the entire document tree all over again for `.button` elements?

Comment: @tadman here's a better question - what's faster, caching the selector or using `this`

Comment: Ye, maybe I talk about selector assigning to new variable. =P

Comment: Your question is sound, but your example is a bit poor. The first example will just hide the clicked element itself. The second example will hide **all** elements matching the selector. Since you didn't use an ID selector here, there can be more than one element having a class `button` ...

Comment: Please do everyone including yourself a favour and do not try to optimize where optimization is not necessary. Premature optimization is usually bad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- You should use `this` if all you want to do is accessing *DOM properties* (that are implemented by all browsers, there are some).

  For example: `this.href` (`<a>`), `this.src` (`<img>`), `this.id` (all elements (if set)), etc.
  This is the fastet way as you don't make a function call to jQuery.
- You should use `$(this)` if you want to apply *jQuery functions* to the DOM element.
- You should **avoid** using `$(selector)` if you already have a reference to that element. Searching the DOM again is way slower.

You can see [in line 92 of the source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L80) that there is not much happening when you pass an HTML element.

---

Also note that `$(this).hide()` and `$('.button').hide();` are not equivalent. The first will only hide the clicked element, while the second will hide all `.button` elements.

Comment: @melee - the test is flawed. You are only benchmarking how long it takes to bind the event handlers. You are not benchmarking how long it takes to perform a select on a click event.

Comment: @Greg actually - I removed it - you're right. I'm working on another test that actually works, haha

Comment: @melee - I think this may be more a more accurate test: http://jsperf.com/thisnthat/2

Answer (score 4):

`this` refers to the actual clicked element where as `$('.button').hide();` would hide all elements with the class `button`.

They don't work the same and even if they would,  `this` would actually be faster since `$('.button')` has to find the element again from the whole document.

Answer (score 2):

Using `$(this)` is slower than using `this` directly, but it is not slower (in general) than hitting the DOM again by using `$('.button')` inside your handler.

The key difference between the two is that `this` is always going to be one element.  `$('.button')` could be any number of elements.  So which you use depends on what you want to hide.

So if you want to work with *the clicked* button **only**:

```
// Fastest if using DOM methods / properties
this.SOME_DOM_METHOD();

// Fastest if using some jQuery method that can take a DOM element
jQuery.method_that_takes_an_element(this, additional, args);

// Fastest if using a jQuery method that cannot take a DOM element
jQuery(this).SOME_JQUERY_METHOD();
```

If you want to work with *all* of elements with a class of `button`:

```
// Fastest if no new .button elements will be created
var buttons = $('.button');
buttons.click(function() {
    buttons.hide();
});

// Slow but I think necessary if new .button elements will be created
$('.some_container').delegate('.button', 'click', function() {
    $('.button').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in first case you hide only one current element.
in second case you just hide everything with class button

Answer (score 1):

`this` points to an already existing object, you don't need to evaluate an expression and find the element *again*, which takes more time and memory.